# How to change base url in VUE router?

Tags: vue.js

Current URL is 'https://localhost:3000/lang/countries/states/cities/'

I want to change it to:

https://localhost:3000/lang/compare/?c=1&back=1&query=94&query=911

Basically I want to edit the current URL. I tried using:

```
  this.$router.push({
    path:'/lang/compare/?c=1&back=1&query=94&query=911',
  });

   this.$router.replace({
   path:'/lang/compare/?c=1&back=1&query=94&query=911',
  });
```

But this changes the URL to :

```
https://localhost:3000/lang/countries/states/cities/lang/compare/?c=1&back=1&query=94&query=911',
```

I have tried using window location href but coz of that state of my variable is lost, hence I need to use VUE router for this. Is their any way to change base URL in VUE routes.

Comment: Could you pls share you router.js file code?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is also right it should work if there is no other issue,

try with

```js
this.$router.push({ path: '/lang/compare', query: { c: 1,back:1,firstquery:94,queryB:991}})
```

or you can  also try with $router name defining a name on router index file

```json
  {
    path: "/lang/compare",
    name: "compare",
    component: comparePage,
  },
```

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'compare', query: { c: 1,back:1,firstquery:94,queryB:991}})
```